# Fastest way to find the maximum real root of cubic function in R

Tags: r

Whats is the fastest way to find the maximum root of a cubic function in R?

```
    a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d = 0
```

Comment: What do you mean by "maximum" root? Can you be more precise?

Comment: @SeñorO But two of three roots are quite likely to be complex-valued...

Comment: It should be real value and highest x-value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is there anything wrong with the base function `polyroot`?

> #### Description
>
> Find zeros of a real or complex polynomial.

An example of a cubic

```
 polyroot(c(1,3,3,1))


 # [1] -1+0i -1+0i -1-0i
```

Here is a function to find the maximum non-complex root of a polynomial...

```
maxReal <- function(params){
  x <- polyroot(params)
  reals <- sapply(x, function(i) isTRUE(all.equal(Im(i),0)))
  max(Re(x)[reals])
  }
```

Comment: +1!.... very fast!here `polyroot(c(d,c,b,a))`
`

Comment: I need the real root not complex.

Comment: @rose The real root is the one where the complex component is 0. You are permitted to perform some work your self in reading the documentation and thinking how to use this function....